# MySQL result ORDER BY date and time

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have query like this

```
"SELECT booking.referance_no AS ref_no,
        booking.entry_date AS dep_date,
        TIME_FORMAT(booking.entry_time,'%H:%i') as dep_time,
        booking.first_name AS fname,
        booking.last_name AS lname,
        booking.mobile AS mobile
    FROM booking WHERE $WHERE1
    GROUP BY booking.book_id
    UNION ALL
SELECT supplier.reference_no AS ref_no,
        DATE_FORMAT(supplier.departure_date_time,'%d-%m-%Y') AS dep_date,
        TIME_FORMAT(supplier.departure_date_time,'%H:%i') AS dep_time,
        supplier.fname AS fname,
        supplier.lname AS lname,
        supplier_subscribers.mobile AS mobile
    FROM supplier WHERE $WHERE2 
    ORDER BY `dep_date` ASC, `dep_time` ASC";
```

and Where Clause

```
$WHERE1="STR_TO_DATE(booking.entry_date, '%d-%M-%Y') BETWEEN '".$from_date." 00:00:00' AND '".$to_date." 23:59:59'";
$WHERE2="supplier.departure_date_time BETWEEN '".$from_date." 00:00:00' AND '".$to_date." 23:59:59'";
```

**Scenario One**

When searching within 24 hours and `ORDER BY dep_date ASC, dep_time ASC` I'm getting result like this

[image: out of order]

check line `63` and `64` in above snapshot the result is sorted by `date` but not by `time` also first result showing from `supplier` table till line `63` and then from `64` onward from table `booking`, it's like the result is sorted by each table (first `supplier` table and then `booking` table) and then sorted by `date` and `time`.

And if search within 24 hours with only `ORDER BY dep_time ASC` I get the correct result properly sorted by time.

**Scenario Two**

If search within 48 hours or more with only `ORDER BY dep_time ASC` I get result as follow

[image: Not in-order 2]

Not Sorted by Date off course it was only sorted by `time`, so it's useless.

And if search within 48 hours or more with  `ORDER BY dep_date ASC, dep_time ASC` I get the same result as first snapshot like;

- First result sorted by table `supplier` and then `booking` but first 24 hours and then next 24 hours
- Then within each 24 hours each table result sorted by `date` and `time` separately.

So how can I sort the result of both tables against `date` and `time` no matter what will be the date range?

Comment: can you please create few sample data at http://sqlfiddle.com and generate the issue? Please do mention the MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Use Concat

```
ORDER BY concat(dep_date,' ',dep_time)` ASC
```

Try the below query, hope this works

```
select * from (SELECT booking.referance_no AS ref_no,
        booking.entry_date AS dep_date,
        TIME_FORMAT(booking.entry_time,'%H:%i') as dep_time,
        booking.first_name AS fname,
        booking.last_name AS lname,
        booking.mobile AS mobile
    FROM booking WHERE $WHERE1
    GROUP BY booking.book_id
    UNION ALL
SELECT supplier.reference_no AS ref_no,
        DATE_FORMAT(supplier.departure_date_time,'%d-%m-%Y') AS dep_date,
        TIME_FORMAT(supplier.departure_date_time,'%H:%i') AS dep_time,
        supplier.fname AS fname,
        supplier.lname AS lname,
        supplier_subscribers.mobile AS mobile
    FROM supplier WHERE $WHERE2 ) as temp ORDER BY concat(dep_date,' ',dep_time)` ASC
```

Comment: No luck bro, same result, each table separately sorted the result by date and time.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You could just `order by` `supplier.departure_date_time` as this is already in the right order.</del>

OK, sorry. I just read the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) about the `UNION` syntax.

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.

```
"
(
SELECT 
  booking.referance_no AS ref_no,
  booking.entry_date AS dep_date,
  TIME_FORMAT(booking.entry_time,'%H:%i') as dep_time,
  booking.first_name AS fname,
  booking.last_name AS lname,
  booking.mobile AS mobile
FROM booking 
WHERE $WHERE1
GROUP BY booking.book_id
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT 
  supplier.reference_no AS ref_no,
  DATE_FORMAT(supplier.departure_date_time,'%d-%m-%Y') AS dep_date,
  TIME_FORMAT(supplier.departure_date_time,'%H:%i') AS dep_time,
  supplier.fname AS fname,
  supplier.lname AS lname,
  supplier_subscribers.mobile AS mobile
FROM supplier 
WHERE $WHERE2
) 
ORDER BY `dep_date` ASC, `dep_time` ASC
";
```

Comment: Query failed: Unknown column 'supplier.departure_date_time' in 'order clause'

Comment: That error suggests you have *ORDER BY  supplier.departure_date_time* rather than *ORDER BY `dep_date` ASC, `dep_time` ASC*