# ORDER BY timestamp not working correctly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, timestamp

I'm trying to sort database entries by the order they were inserted. The `regTime` column is in tblContestant and is of type timestamp. I don't apply a formatting mask to the timestamp anywhere in the code.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tblContestant c, tblParticipation p
WHERE c.AGANumber = ? AND p.AGANumber = c.AGANumber
ORDER BY regTime DESC
```

Here's the output. It's mostly in order, except for the 1st, 2nds and 4th entries.

[image: my output]

Comment: Yes, bug in MySQL. Switch to MariaDB for a solution on this one. There are a few more like these, and they do not seem to be solved real quick by the MySQL team right now.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen - can you link to the bug report please?

Comment: @zzxjoanw - what version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: Yeah, [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43099) is one of the bug reports.  The system converts the datetime to a string based on `DATE_FORMAT` and then sorts them as strings.  Note that MySQL has this flagged as "Not a bug".  I guess you'd have to `ORDER BY DATEFORMAT(regTime, '%y-%m-%d %T')`

Comment: Thanks, Norbert! Unfortunately, I can't switch db software for this project, do you know if there's a workaround for the bug?

Comment: That bug is when sorting on a column that is a formatted date time. Hence it is sorting on a string representation of the date. That is not the problem here where the SELECT is ordering based on the actual date / time column (which is the way given by the posted of that bug to avoid the problem).

Comment: Something is very strange here. Can you post the actual table declares and some sample data to demonstrate the problem. The data is not in any way sorted according to the ORDER BY clause as it should be sorted DESCending. Looks more like the script that processes the result of that query has itself sorted the results.

Comment: it's a big bug, issue occurs when joining 2 or more then 2 tables and sorting the data by date & time either in ASC or DESC order. if you run the same query separate for each table, the result will be sorted properly ASC or DESC but 2 or more tables join, not be able to sort the result by date and time. (Work around: if you are fetching data only for 24 hours you can sort the data by only `time` and you will have desired result but if you try with 48 hours the result will be messed up)

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380953/mysql-result-order-by-date-and-time my scenario is bit different then yours (you have JOIN in the table and i have UNION but output result is not sorted by date and time and I tried every possible way i know, found on SO and google, suggestions, recommendation, but end result is same, data not sorted by date and time

Comment: The UNION issue is completely different and not a bug. It is associating the ORDER BY clause with the 2nd unioned select statement, hence why the mysql manual pages tell you to put the individual selects within brackets to split them from the order by clause.